# How to count the frequency of values occur for a particular row across all columns

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a data frame with four columns and part of this is like:

```
C1 C2 C3 C4
60 60 60 60
59 59 58 58
0  0  0  0
12 13 13 11
```

Now i want to create four columns each corresponding to the frequency of each values considering other three columns like the columns will look like:

```
F1 F2 F3 F4
4  4  4  4
2  2  2  2
2  2  2  2
1  2  2  1
```

In the cell 1,1 the value is 4 because the value 60 appears in all the columns for the particular rows.
In cell 4,1 the value is 1 as 12 appears in no other columns for the particular row.
I need to  calculate and add the features F1,F2,F3,F4 in the pandas data frame.

Comment: @Alex_ban - what is output if instead value `12` is `58` ?

Comment: You mean the last row. It will be 1.

Comment: @jezrael even though 58 appears in second row , the appearance of 58 instead of 12 won't change things as they are in different rows.

Comment: @Alex_ban - thank you for explanation, now solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) `axis=1` for process by rows with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by frequencies by [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.map(x.value_counts()),axis=1)
print (df)
   C1  C2  C3  C4
0   4   4   4   4
1   2   2   2   2
2   4   4   4   4
3   1   2   2   1
```

Comment: Thanks the second one looks easier.

Comment: yes I want to calculate the  frequency of occurrence of a value  throughout all columns of that particular row.